# Tag [frontend] não deveria ser [front-end]? (assim como existe [back-end])

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags, tag-específica, tags-sinônimas

Eu não estou discutindo aqui se a tag é boa ou ruim (se bem que pessoalmente acho ela mais uma das inúteis tags que ajudam tão minimamente que nem precisariam existir :P), a questão é que criaram a tag assim [frontend](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend), enquanto [back-end](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/back-end) tem o hífen.

Não seria o caso de edita-la (se possivel) e sugerir [frontend](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend) como "sinônimo de tag"?

Comment: Onde você viu essa *tag* ? :D

Comment: Eu já fiz ;D :D